# Lines simultaneously tangent to the curves $y = x^2$ and $y = -x^2+2x-2$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, analytic-geometry, tangent-line

Is (are) there any straight line(s) that is (are) simultaneously tangent to both the curves given by the equations $y = x^2$ and $y = -x^2+2x-2$?

My Attempt:

> Let $y = mx+b$ be any such (non-vertical) line. Then we must have
> $$
> mx+b = x^2 \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad mx+b = -x^2+2x-2,
> $$
> or in other words,
> $$
> x^2 - mx-b = 0 \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad x^2 + (m-2)x + (b+2) = 0.
> $$
> Moreover, each one of these two quadratics must have coincident solutions, which implies that each one of the two discriminants must be zero, that is, we must have
> $$
> m^2 + 4b = 0 \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad (m-2)^2 -4 (b+2) = 0,
> $$
> and from the first of the preceding two relations we get
> $$
> b = - \frac{m^2}{4},
> $$
> which when substituted into the second one gives
> $$
> (m-2)^2 + m^2 - 8 = 0,
> $$
> which simplifies to
> $$
> 2m^2 -4m -4 = 0,
> $$
> and hence
> $$
> m^2 - 2m - 2 = 0,
> $$
> from which we get
> $$
> m = \frac{ 2 \pm \sqrt{4 + 8} }{2} = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{12}}{2} = 1 \pm \sqrt{3}.
> $$
> For $m = 1 + \sqrt{3}$, we get
> $$ b = - \frac{ (1 + \sqrt{3})^2 }{4} = - \frac{ 4 + 2 \sqrt{3} }{4} = -1 - \frac{ \sqrt{3} }{2}. $$

> And, for $m = 1- \sqrt{3}$, we get
> $$
> b = - \frac{ (1 - \sqrt{3})^2 }{4} = - \frac{ 4 - 2 \sqrt{3} }{4} = -1 + \frac{ \sqrt{3} }{2}.
> $$

> Thus there are two straight lines that are simultaneously tangent to both the given curves, and these lines are given by the equations
> $$
> y = (1 + \sqrt{3} ) x  -1 - \frac{ \sqrt{3} }{2}
> $$
> and
> $$
> y = (1 - \sqrt{3} ) x  -1 + \frac{ \sqrt{3} }{2}.
> $$

Is my solution / answer correct? If so, then is my approach to finding this solution / answer also correct? If not, then where have I erred?

Any alternative solutions, especially those using the methods of differential calculus?

Comment: any such line passes through $(\frac{1}{2}, - \frac{1}{2})$  Do yo know how to find the tangent s to a parabola through a point outside it?

Answer (score 1):

To determine the tangent lines is sufficient to solve for $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ the system

$$
\cases{
y_1 = x_1^2\\
y_2 = -x_2^2+2x_2-2\\
y_1 = m x_1 + c\\
y_2 = m x_2 + c
}
$$

so a typical result is

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
x_1& = &  \frac{1}{2} \left(m-\sqrt{4 c+m^2}\right) \\
y_1 & = &  \frac{1}{2} m \left(m-\sqrt{4 c+m^2}\right)+c \\
x_2 & = & \frac{1}{2} \left(2-\sqrt{(m-4) m-4c-4}-m\right) \\
y_2 & = & c-\frac{1}{2} m \left(\sqrt{(m-4) m-4c-4}+m-2\right) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

from here, we solve the tangency conditions

$$
\cases{
4 c+m^2 = 0\\
(m-4) m-4c-4=0
}
$$

obtaining

$$
\cases{
m = 1\pm \sqrt{3}\\
c=-\frac 14\left(1\pm\sqrt{3}\right)^2
}
$$